# Get bites from AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, ios5, avaudiorecorder

Hello I'm kind of new in iOS and I have a particular task, first I record a sound with AVAudioRecorder and I can record and play it without troubles, but I need to get the data in bites of the record here are my functions:

```
@interface recordViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    UIButton *playButton;
    UIButton *recordButton;
    UIButton *stopButton;
}
```

Record:

```
 -(void) recordAudio {
     if (!audioRecorder.recording)
     {
         playButton.enabled = NO;
         stopButton.enabled = YES;
         [audioRecorder record];
     }
}
```

Play:

```
-(void) playAudio {
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        stopButton.enabled = YES;
        recordButton.enabled = NO;

        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                       initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url
                       error:&error];

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    } 
}
```

How can I get the data in bites of the record? I searched in iOS Developer API and I cant find anything, Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this solution.  But this could help.  Try it.

To Record a Audio:

```
itsVoiceRecordedURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:<Path of the recorded file to be stored>]];
    NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    itsAudioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:itsVoiceRecordedURL settings:recordSetting error:&error];
    [recordSetting release];
    [itsAudioRecorder setDelegate:self];
    //We call this to start the recording process and initialize 
    //the subsstems so that when we actually say "record" it starts right away.
    [itsAudioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    //Start the actual Recording
    [itsAudioRecorder record];
```

To convert the recorded audio file to Byte Array

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:AudioFilePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
```